# ModernCV \social hyperlink not working despite working email hyperline

Tags: moderncv, links

```
\email{first.last@colorado.edu}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/name/]{name}
```

The hyperlink works within the generated preview within Texshop but when I export as PDF and view in Preview or Adobe Acrobat I am unable to click the LinkedIn hyperlink despite being able to click the email hyperlink.

Any thoughts/input would be greatly appreciated. I've looked at all related questions in this forum regarding my problem and have tried all solutions but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Does `\social[linkedin]{name}`work? (There seems to be no second optional argument.)

Comment: Ok, there is a second optional argument. But your URL is the same as used by ModernCV, just without the `/` at the end. So removing the `/` may also help.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem using the [`moderncv` template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex). See [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1M78.png) that correctly shows the URL and is clickable. If you can provide the community with something that replicates your problem, maybe then we can help.

Comment: hey guys so the problem still persists but I seem to have narrowed down what the issue is but still the problem persists. When I omit the second argument {with my name} the hyperlink is inactive; however, if I leave that argument blank the hyperlink works seeing as how its an actual link. Any thoughts